# grails - using variable values in remoteFunction attributes

Tags: grails

[please start at comment to see where this problem is currently at, thanks. Hopefully fast/easy to read thru]

I've got a situation where I'm rendering a template, and the template has a javascript function that needs to send correct values to a controller action via a remoteFunction, e.g. below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function updateOrderEntry() {
    alert("updating OrderEntries");
    var unused = ${remoteFunction(action:'userByName', id:userId, update:[success: 'userOrderList', failure: 'userOrderListError'])};
  }
</script>
```

I get the alert and "call" into the controller fine when this function gets executed on the page, but it is not sending an id value (params doesn't contain an id).   When I build the template, I provide the userId as a model parameter and I have verified that it makes it into the template fine (e.g. in a div).

I've tried a bunch of variants of the above but can't get it to work, e.g. using remoteFunction as a tag:

```
 var unused = <g:remoteFunction action="userByName" id="${userId}" update="[success: 'userOrderList', failure: 'userOrderListError']" />;
```

I also tried various flavors using the params attribute (which would be better), but after not getting that to work I thought I'd try just to get the id parameter working.

What am I doing wrong as I attempt to variably populate the remoteFunction attribute(s)?

Thanks

[project is on Grails 1.3.7]

---

-------------------------------- update per 1st/2nd comment -----------------------------------

Had no URL mappings for this controller, but removed the one I had for another controller.  Also ***commented out*** the beforeInterceptor debug I had in this controller, namely:

```
  // def beforeInterceptor = [action: this.&debug]

  // def debug() {
  //  println "ACTION: ${actionUri}, PARAMS: ${params}"
  // }
```

I added in debug code to the top of my userByName action, namely:

```
 def userByName = {
    println "action: ${actionUri}, params: ${params}"
```

I also did 3 versions of the remoteFunction that is sent back from the controller in the template, with all ***3 identical, except*** the second one uses a userId that is hard coded, instead of produced from a variable, namely:

```
 function updateOrderEntry() {
    alert("updating OrderEntries, 1st time");

    var unused = ${remoteFunction(action:'userByName', id:userId, params:[userId:userId], update:[success: 'userOrderList', failure: 'userOrderListError'])};

    alert("updating OrderEntries, 2nd time, THIS TIME WITH hardcoded id and param values");
    var unused = ${remoteFunction(action:'userByName', id:'4', params:[userId:'4'], update:[success: 'userOrderList', failure: 'userOrderListError'])};

    alert("updating OrderEntries, 3rd time, back to non-hard-coded values");
    var unused = ${remoteFunction(action:'userByName', id:userId, params:[userId:userId], update:[success: 'userOrderList', failure: 'userOrderListError'])};
}
```

When this function is sent back to the browser (from the render template), the browser (Chrome, using its network debug) shows it receives:

```
   function updateOrderEntry() {
    alert("updating OrderEntries, 1st time");

    var unused = jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:{'userId': '4'}, url:'/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/userByName/4',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#userOrderList').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){jQuery('#userOrderListError').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);}});;

    alert("updating OrderEntries, 2nd time, THIS TIME WITH hardcoded id and param values");
    var unused = jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:{'userId': '4'}, url:'/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/userByName/4',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#userOrderList').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){jQuery('#userOrderListError').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);}});;

    alert("updating OrderEntries, 3rd time, back to non-hard-coded values");
    var unused = jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:{'userId': '4'}, url:'/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/userByName/4',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#userOrderList').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){jQuery('#userOrderListError').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);}});;
}
```

All of these look identical to me.   The updateOrderEntry() gets automatically invoked, and I see all 3 alerts as shown above.   Correspondingly, at the server, I see the following debug output:

```
action: /money/userByName, params: [userId:null, action:userByName, controller:money]
action: /money/userByName, params: [userId:4, id:4, action:userByName, controller:money]
action: /money/userByName, params: [userId:null, action:userByName, controller:money]
```

The problem is, the userId or id is not getting set correctly (as seen at the server) in the 1st and 3rd remoteFunctions, not clear why that is.  Something is different, just can't figure out what.

P.S. Results are the same using both Chrome and Firefox.

---

------ updated per comments 3 - 5 below --------------------------

Looking at Chrome in what it sends, the middle, good request looks like:

```
 Request URL:http://localhost:8080/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/userByName/4
 Request Method:POST
 Status Code:200 OK
 Request Headersview source
 Accept:*/*
 Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
 Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
 Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
 Connection:keep-alive
 Content-Length:8
 Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Cookie:JSESSIONID=F0FDCEE323A1834350E209A7C211E64D
 Host:localhost:8080
 Origin:http://localhost:8080
 Referer:http://localhost:8080/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/transaction
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7
 X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
 Form Dataview URL encoded
   userId:4
```

The 2 bad ones (note 1st and last lines, as well as ?) are:

```
 Request URL:http://localhost:8080/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/userByName
 Request Method:POST
 Status Code:200 OK
 Request Headersview source
 Accept:*/*
 Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
 Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
 Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
 Connection:keep-alive
 Content-Length:11
 Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Cookie:JSESSIONID=F0FDCEE323A1834350E209A7C211E64D
 Host:localhost:8080
 Origin:http://localhost:8080
 Referer:http://localhost:8080/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/transaction
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7
 X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
 Form Dataview URL encoded
   userId:null
```

So, this shows what the browser is sending is different.

When, I hard coded the value I gave to the template, i.e. model: [...., userId: '4'], I got the same failed result.  Before I was using:  model: [...., userId: order.user.id], but I updated my debug output and confirmed even hard-coding the '4' here doesn't help.

---

UPDATE:  Adding minimal Test Case that matches real code.  Note: the real code is a page with 3 sections, the top is fixed, where a customer is selected; the middle section is updated with orders for that customer; and the bottom section shows the credit card transactions associated via the order, usually multiple ones (e.g. authorize, capture, void, etc).  When the user does an action (e.g. void) in the bottom transaction section, not only does it need to update this section, but also the middle order section. I was trying to get the order section -- the "**second** div" -- to update by using a link/remoteFunction on the bottom transaction section, and in its onComplete handler, calling a Javascript function that would do a second remoteFunction, to cause the middle order section to update.

Below is a minimal test case where I am not able to reproduce the problem exactly, but interestingly found a different but related problem.  It appears Grails (or somehow IntelliJ, my IDE), has problems with an id parameter specified in the remoteFunction, when it is inside of Javascript.  When you run it, you'll see what I mean.  Hopefully fast to copy in the code and run.  Thanks.

----  some simple controller, no model needed ----

```
 class UiTestController {

   static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

  def index = {
    println "rendering remoteTest"
    render(view: 'remoteTest')
  }

  def section1 = {
    println "action1 params: ${params}"

    render(template: 'remoteSection1', model: [id: params.id])
  }

  def section2 = {
    println "action2 params: ${params}"
    render(template: 'remoteSection2', model: [id: params.id])
  }
}
```

---  remoteTest.gsp --

```
 <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Remote</title>
   <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
</head>
<body>

   <div style="text-decoration:underline; color:purple; cursor:pointer; margin: 20px"
    onclick="${remoteFunction(action: 'section1', id:'1', update: 'section1')}">click to update section 1</div>
   <br />
   <div id="section1">1st Section to Update</div>
   <br />
   <div id="section2">2nd Section to Update</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

----  _remoteSection1.gsp -----

```
  <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>

 <div>
     <p>Section 1 updated, (id=${id}). Now, similar to real code, we
     <span style="text-decoration:underline; color:purple; cursor:pointer;"
          onclick="${remoteFunction(action: 'section2', id: '2', update: 'section2')}">update section 2</span>
    </p>
 </div>
```

----  _remoteSection2.gsp -----

```
 <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function updateSection1() {
        alert("doing remoteFunction with fixed value 55");
        var unused = ${remoteFunction(action: 'section1', id='55', update: 'section1')};
        alert("doing remoteFunction with fixed value 65, using params");
        var unused = ${remoteFunction(action: 'section1', params:[id:'65'], update: 'section1')};
  } 
  </script>

  <div>
      <p>Section 2 updated, (id=${id}). Now, similar to real code, we
      <span style="text-decoration:underline; color:purple; cursor:pointer;"
          onclick="${remoteFunction(action: 'section2', id: '2', update: 'section2', onComplete: 'updateSection1()')}">update section 2 again, and also section 1 with javascript updateSection1() function</span>
     </p>
  </div>
```

---

---

```
FINAL UPDATE
```

---

---

Code is now working, reason for change is unknown.  I had to go on to a few other tasks, and I have come back to this one with changes to my controller, and surprisingly things are working.  Same Javascript calls as before.  But I will quickly post it in case you see that there was some kind of mess up before:

--------------------------  Pertinent Javascript Code in _moneyEntries.gsp --------------------------

```
  function updateOrderEntry() {
    alert("Updating OrderEntries --  1st time");
    ${remoteFunction(action:'userByName', id:userId, update:[success: 'userOrderList', failure: 'userOrderListError'])};

    alert("Updating OrderEntries -- 2nd time, THIS TIME WITH hardcoded id and param values");
    ${remoteFunction(action:'userByName', params:[id: '4'], update:[success: 'userOrderList', failure: 'userOrderListError'])};

    alert("Updating OrderEntries -- 3rd time, back to non-hard-coded values");
    ${remoteFunction(action:'userByName', params:[id: userId], update:[success: 'userOrderList', failure: 'userOrderListError'])};

 }
```

----------------   What Google network view shows me -- entire response --------------

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/nameIsInAppPropsFile/plugins/jquery-       1.6.1.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function confirmVoid(moneyTransId) {
       return confirm("Void transaction ID " +moneyTransId + ":");
    }

   function confirmCredit(moneyTransId, amountIn) {
     var valid = false;
     var amount = amountIn;
    while (!valid) {
        var r = prompt("For ID " +moneyTransId+ ", please specify the amount:", amount);
        if (r == null || r == "") {
            valid = true;
            amount = -1;
        } else {
            //alert("result is:" +r);
            if (r > amount) {
                alert("You cannot credit an amount greater than " + amount);
                amount = amountIn;
            }
            else {
                amount = r;
                // invoke remote function, update result
                valid = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return amount;
}

function confirmCapture(moneyTransId) {
    return confirm("Capture funds for ID " +moneyTransId + ":");
}

function confirmSend(moneyTransId) {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to send an email receipt for ID " +moneyTransId + ":");
}
    //var unused = jQuery.ajax({type:'POST', url:'/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/userByName/3',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#userOrderList').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){jQuery('#userOrderListError').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);}});;

function updateOrderEntry() {
    alert("Updating OrderEntries --  1st time");
    jQuery.ajax({type:'POST', url:'/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/userByName/8',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#userOrderList').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){jQuery('#userOrderListError').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);}});;

    alert("Updating OrderEntries -- 2nd time, THIS TIME WITH hardcoded id and param values");
    jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:{'id': '4'}, url:'/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/userByName',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#userOrderList').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){jQuery('#userOrderListError').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);}});;

    alert("Updating OrderEntries -- 3rd time, back to non-hard-coded values");
    jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:{'id': '8'}, url:'/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/userByName',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#userOrderList').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){jQuery('#userOrderListError').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);}});;

}


 </script>

 <div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:9px;">Order # 1005 Merchant Transactions:
    <span class="jsAction" style="padding-left:30px"
          onclick="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:{'userId': '8'}, url:'/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/userByName',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#userOrderList').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){jQuery('#userOrderListError').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);}});; return false;">(refresh order status)</span></div>
<div class="list">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>What Action?</th>
            <th class="sortable" ><a href="/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/voidTrans/12?sort=id&amp;order=asc">ID</a></th>

            <th class="sortable" ><a href="/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/voidTrans/12?sort=dateCreated&amp;order=asc">Date</a></th>

            <th class="sortable" ><a href="/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/voidTrans/12?sort=type&amp;order=asc">Transaction Type</a></th>

            <th class="sortable" ><a href="/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/voidTrans/12?sort=responseCode&amp;order=asc">Result</a></th>

            <th class="sortable" ><a href="/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/voidTrans/12?sort=totalAmt&amp;order=asc">Amount</a></th>

            <th class="sortable" ><a href="/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/voidTrans/12?sort=description&amp;order=asc">Description</a></th>

            <th class="sortable" ><a href="/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/voidTrans/12?sort=txid&amp;order=asc">Authorize.Net Transaction Id</a></th>

            <th class="sortable" ><a href="/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/voidTrans/12?sort=responseReasonText&amp;order=asc">Authorize.Net Response Text</a></th>

            <th class="sortable" ><a href="/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/voidTrans/12?sort=ccNumber&amp;order=asc">Credit Card #</a></th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr class="odd">

                <td>
                   <!-- First Check for transaction validity, for it to be 'actionable' -->

                      none

                   </td>


                <td>13</td>

                <td>01-13-12 03:41 MST</td>

                <td>VOID OF previous authorization, ID 12</td>

                <td><span class="">
                        Approved</span></td>

                <td>NA</td>

                <td>Void: sfk .</td>


                <td>2168161109</td>

                <td><span class="">
                    This transaction has been approved.</span></td>

                <td></td>

            </tr>

            <tr class="even">

                <td>
                   <!-- First Check for transaction validity, for it to be 'actionable' -->
                   none
                   </td>


                <td>12</td>

                <td>01-13-12 03:41 MST</td>

                <td>AUTHORIZATION ONLY - then Voided in ID 13</td>

                <td><span class="">
                        Approved</span></td>

                <td>$11</td>

                <td>sfk .</td>


                <td>2168161109</td>

                <td><span class="">
                    This transaction has been approved.</span></td>

                <td>x9113</td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>

   <!--div class="paginateButtons">

   </div-->
 </div>
```

--------------------------  What the Debug output shows in the controller -----

```
 ACTION: /money/userByName, PARAMS: [id:8, action:userByName, controller:money]
 ACTION: /money/userByName, PARAMS: [id:4, action:userByName, controller:money]
 ACTION: /money/userByName, PARAMS: [id:8, action:userByName, controller:money]
```

So, I don't know why it is working now, and not before.  But the updateOrderEntry() is the same.  Perhaps you see something I did wrong before, in which case please let me know.  Thanks again for all your help Tomasz, I learned a lot being able to debug with Google Chrome (thanks to your help).

Comment: Do you have any UrlMappings specified for this controller and action? I suspect that you try to parse userId and it fails. Also do `println params` as the first line in this action and show us the output.

Comment: @Tomasz - thanks, I updated this per your comments.  It is in the problem statement, see:  ---- update per 1st/2nd comment ------

Comment: Maybe you've used `userId: 4`, instead of `userId: '4'` in second one? My other hint: use Chrome, right click and Inspect element, switch to Network tab and you can see exactly what AJAX request and responses are sent and received like here : http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/network.html . Check if your params are sent.

Comment: @Tomasz thanks for your response.  In the model that I give to the render I hardcoded the userId value there to 4, namely: model: [ ...,  userId: '4'].  This produced the same result unfortunately.  I'm going to try to see what Chrome is SENDING over the wire per your second comment/manual.  Please note though what I see being sent to the browser above in the 3 cases.

Comment: @Tomasz - I looked at what is sent, the deficiency does appear to be there, namely for the middle hard-coded one, ... well, let me post above.

Comment: it can't be! :) Take a look once again at `function updateOrderEntry()` when it's rendered with these 3 lines. View page source, copy it and paste it here. Three same lines cannot produce two different requests. It application is live you can paste an URL so I can see it for myself.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, I re-ran it, and the 3 lines are identical to what is shown above (a copy/paste out of Google's Network Tools).  The app is not yet live, so I can't give you a link to test.  But I am generating a "minimal" example that will hopefully reproduce the problem, and I will paste it above. I'm wondering if Grails is depositing a control-character in there somewhere and it doesn't show up, but messes things up. Thanks again for your help.  I hope to get the little example running (and failing) soon.

Comment: do you have minimal test-case? I wait for it. Or you can have your rendered page save-as and send me to look at it.

Comment: there is en error in your test case: `id='55'` and it should be `id:'55'`. After you change this everything works fine. I guess there is a problem somewhere but you missed it in description, where you obviously don't want to reveal details about your application. Search for typos like this one or paste your exactly generated code. Otherwise I won't be able to help you.

Comment: Another suggestion: start your live application and open Chrome network tab. Look closely what are AJAX responses. I guess you don't set userId or id variables in some response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It rendered fine for me, Grails 2.0, I've set `def userId = 7` and as you can see it appears in URL:

```
            function updateOrderEntry() {
                alert("updating OrderEntries");
                var unused = jQuery.ajax({type:'POST', 
                    url:'/controller/userByName/7',
                    success:function(data,textStatus)
                        {jQuery('#userOrderList').html(data);},
                    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown)
                        {jQuery('#userOrderListError').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);}
            });;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm still on Grails 1.3.7 for this project.  Can you tell me the tool/way you are able to see this output -- i.e. the resulting javascript put into the browser page, that comes from a render of a template?   When I use "View Page Source" in Firefox or a "View Source" in Chrome, I don't see the results deposited into the browser via the rendering of a template, neither the Javascript or the html tags that were deposited.

Comment: @Ray for Firefox you can install Firebug [link](http://getfirebug.com/) and for Chrome it's installed by default. Right-click on an element you want to inspect and select "Inspect element". You will see entire page's DOM and many more useful information.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz.  I see it now.  Amazingly the url sent back to the browser looks like: url:'/nameIsInAppPropsFile/money/userByName/4'.  But, when that link gets invoked my Grails debug shows: ACTION: /money/userByName, PARAMS: [action:userByName, controller:money] -- no ID parameter.  So, not sure what is going on.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, I updated the problem description to show everything clearer, now also using the params attribute of remoteFunction.  Any thoughts on what the issue is, why the params or id isn't coming through to the server (as seen/shown by grails).

Comment: Tomasz - thanks.  Please note I updated the problem description per your comment on the problem.

Comment: Tomasz -- thanks again for your support.  I updated the problem description.  It looks like what the browser is sending is different in the failed case.  But, when I see what it is receiving -- i.e. the 3 jQuery.ajax expanded code above, they all 3 look identical.  But, they must not be??

Comment: Thanks for your question Tomasz.  I added a simple example and explanation to what I'm doing (above).  For some reason the simple example has a problem populating the ID, as does the real code, but not the params section (not sure why).  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tomasz and kind assistance. Please note I wish there was a way to upload all my code so you could run it directly.  I'm going to explore what you said in the next day and get back.  Please note your guidance so far has been very helpful, in understanding how to debug better using Chrome, and other stuff (e.g. today's comments).  So, thanks again!

Comment: Hi Tomasz, I had to go onto other tasks and I am back to this one.  The controller changed some but not the views -- not the Javascript stuff, but it is working now for some reason! I saw the error you sent regarding the example I made, which was good, but I had no such error in my real Javascript code that I can see (and was shown in the top part of this problem.  Perhaps you see a change that got made so that it now works? Note I included the updated code and the whole template/GSP as seen by Chrome.  Perhaps you see something that changed?  I will come back and check if you respond. Thanks!

Comment: @Ray I'm glad it works now. Too bad we won't ever find out what was wrong. I don't see any new differences. Post new questions if you have any, here on StackOverflow. Good luck! :)

Comment: :-)  Thanks again Tomasz ...  the Chrome help was definitely great.  If I ever figure out what was wrong, I'll update here.  Hey, separately, do you have any thoughts on the best way for remoteFunction to update two or more unrelated divs (on success)?  I.e. I did it updating one div, then causing onSuccess to "call"  another action to update the second div, but I suspect that's not the cleanest way

Comment: @Ray post it on SO as a question. I, or others will surely reply :)

Answer (score 0):

this is how params work in a remoteFunction:

```
....
params:'\'id=\'+document.getElementById(\'idField\').value',
.....
```